# Vertically aligning headings in Bootstrap with different fontsizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand there are a ton of posts on this subject, but none of them worked for me. How do I align headings with different fontsizes vertically? I tried vertical-align: bottom, but didn't work for me.

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 id="h1">Computer Science and Engineering</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h4 id="h2">"Ss. Cyril & Methodius" University - Skopje</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


<style>
    nav { border-radius: 0 !important;}
    #h1, #h2 { vertical-align: bottom; !important;}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: take a look at your inspector in your browser at the h1,h2 elements, h1 probably just has margin-top or something.

Comment: you could look at css styling to style like a table cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even simply write it in single h1 tag and inside that use span tag. See below code, it may help you.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title> Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      nav {
        border-radius: 0 !important;
      }

      #h1 {
        vertical-align: bottom !important;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2 id="h1">
              Computer Science and Engineering
              <span style="font-size: 20px;color:gray;">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;"Ss. Cyril & Methodius" University - Skopje
              </span>
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use line-height, margin or padding

```
#h2 { line-height:XXpx;}
#h2 { margin:XXpx XXpx;}
#h2 { padding:XXpx;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the columns are block element so `vertical-align` won't work.

One solution is to adjust the top margin on the smaller heading as needed:

```
#h2 { 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/jrexdrKpOC